# When writing a model spec, is there a difference between checking validity and a successful save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When writing a spec for a Rails model, is there a difference between checking whether the model should be valid, and whether save should be true? I see in other code bases that these two conditions are tested independently, but the Rails API seems to explain that this validation check is ran when save is called.

Is there any condition in which a model could be valid but not save?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, database could be down. A non-validation-related callback could fail.

But the point is that tests should test small isolated bits, so validation logic is tested separately.